# Avoiding character being echoed over text widget in tkinter but subsequent handles being called

Tags: python, events, text, tkinter, widget

i need to get showY handled as well as showX i could just change the order
but the situation is more complex than that.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(master=root)
text.pack()

def showX(event):
    print 'handle 1'
    # return """I need to return something that permits showY being trigged
           # but the character x not being echoed over the text area.
           # 'break' avoids the character being echoed but avoids showY being hand           led"""
    return 'break'

def showY(event):
    print 'handle 2'

# it seems that even with add=True tkinter doesnt match Key-X as Shift-X.
# they are separate events.
text.bind('<Key-x>', showY, add=True)
text.bind('<KeyPress-x>', showX, add=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#I need to return something that permits showY being trigged
# but the character x not being echoed over the text area.
```

I assume you mean something other than calling showY from the showX function. The work around is to use a third function, assuming the program dictates that two functions are necessary because you want just a showY option as well.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(master=root)
text.insert(END, "abc")
text.pack()

def show_both(event):
    showX(event)
    showY(event)
    return 'break'

def showX(event):
    print 'handle 1'

def showY(event):
    print 'handle 2'

##text.bind('<Key-x>', showY, add=True)
text.bind('<KeyPress-x>', show_both, add=True)
root.mainloop()
```